# java useDelimiter and nextDouble

Tags: java, file-io

I am have the following code

```
Scanner isbnTable = new Scanner(isbnFile);
isbnTable.useDelimiter("[;,\\n]");
while(isbnTable.hasNextDouble())System.out.println(isbnTable.nextDouble());
```

and I'm reading a file with the contents

```
3.10;8.35;5.96
7.36;6.25;9.32
```

However the output is

```
3.1
8.35
```

Why doesn't it show all of the numbers

Comment: because `\\n` might not be the new line character. My advice use something like  `[^.0-9]` as delimiter or read the line as String and split based on `;` (faster option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I was using a file with windows end of line encoding. The solution is to use

```
isbnTable.useDelimiter(";|\r\n|\n");
```